# Magento 2,Fotorama api ,How to add and play custom video in product page.

Tags: magento2

I want to add and play custom video where product images are display.
Can any one help me?

Comment: Refer this link : https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-add-custom-product-video-in-fotorama-gallery/

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/gallery/gallery',
    ], function ($) {
        
        $('[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]').on('gallery:loaded', function () {

            // $(this).on('fotorama:ready', function () {

            var api = $(this).data('gallery');

            var video = {
                id: 'ZpFrNyD4100',
                source: 'youtube',
                caption: 'Magento Commerce'
            }

            api.fotorama.data.push({
                video: {
                    id: video.id,
                    p: 'https://',
                    s: '',
                    type:  video.source,
                },
                isMain: false,
                type: 'video',
                caption: video.caption
            });
            // });
        });
    });
</script>
```

For reference:

- [Magento 2 DevDocs - Gallery Widget](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_gallery.html)
- [Fotorama Docs - API](https://fotorama.io/docs/4/api/)

Comment: I have followed this method, i got "Uncaught ReferenceError: video is not defined
    at images.js:3120 " this error. Can you please let me know where you defined 'video'? please check my code, https://nimb.ws/YsG1UL

Comment: I've updatet the answer with a working example

Comment: Thanks, It works fine for me!!